# Virtual Machine cannot start

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, virtualization, hyper-v, virtual-machines

I have just installed Windows Server 2008R2 on a brand new Dell T320 Server to act as a hyper visor for an SBS 2011 VM.

As with all new builds I have;

- Confirmed the CPU supports virtualisation.
- Confirmed virtualisation is enabled in the BIOS.
- Installed all device drivers.
- Installed the Hyper-V role.
- Rebooted at all Windows requests.
- Installed all required updates.

So in theory I should be able to create/import a Virtual Machine and start it? Well I always thought so, I get the following error.

```
An error occurred while attempting to start the selected Virtual Machine(s).
"New Virtual Machine" could not be initialized. (Virtual Machine ID: XXXXXXXX).
```

I read on TechNet this can be related to permissions of VHD's/XML config files so I can confirm all NTFS ACL's have acceptable permissions to work correctly. Also I have never had this issue before, and I have build around 20 Windows Hyper-Visors.

I also have tried pointing the creation of the new VM to a different partition to get it away from Windows, no difference. I am still copying over my backed up VHD so that I can try 'Importing' a VM instead of creating an entirely new one.

Some forum also mentioned about checking the IDE controller was correctly configured so I have compared this to a health Windows Server 2008R2 hyper-visor at it appears to be configured correctly.

Any thoughts would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution on this website http://byronwright.blogspot.co.uk/2011/10/hyper-v-vm-unable-to-start.html

Installed the hotfix and it has sorted the problem.

Comment: Seriously? YOu are awae that is on a Server WITHOUT SP1 INSTALLED? You do not like patching up that "brand new" machine before putting it into production? To Quote from your link: "The simple solution is to install Windows 2008 R2 SP1"